# Problems with gdb: No debugging symbols found

Tags: c, gcc, terminal, gdb

I have a problem when it comes to running gdb. I've been given two files. the source code `hello.c` and a 64-bit ELF called `hello`

I want to run gdb but when I run `gdb ./hello` I get the message `(No debugging symbols found in hello)`

I can't seem to find out why this happens, and I can't find anyone that has had the same problem before where the, this case `hello` file is given. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That happens because you built the executable without debug information, or else stripped the debug information from the executable after it was built.  The latter seeming unlikely to me, I imagine you can resolve the issue by recompiling with the `-g` compiler option.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the already given executable obsolete? Cause I'm creating a new executable. I'm totally new to using c so all this is completely new to me.

Comment: Yes, you must *rebuild* the executable if you want one that contains debug symbols.  Just rerun the compilation command, something like `gcc -g -o hello hello.c`. Keep a copy of the original executable if that's important.

Comment: If you are not permitted to rebuild it then you cannot rely on debugging symbols (but `gdb` can still be of *some* use without them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compile the program again with the -g flag.

gcc -g -o hello hello.c

Run gdb with generated executable:

gdb ./hello

now you are able to see this kind of message:

Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./hello...done.
(gdb)