# creating a linkedlist of strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So I wanted to make a hexadecimal to binary converting function in c and my plan of implementation was to change the characters in hex to a string of binary numbers
put that string of characater arrays into a linkedlist
and print out said linked list
however when I run it it segfaults and I don't really know how to debug using gdb considering it is in assembly
hence could someone point me out to where I went wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "h2b.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        hexToBinary(argv[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

typedef struct hexString{
    char* data;
    struct hexString* next;
}hexString;


hexString* head= NULL;

void add(char* bits, hexString* ptr){
    hexString* temp = (hexString*)malloc(sizeof(hexString));
    temp->data = bits;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
            head = temp;
    }
    else{
            ptr = head;
            while(ptr->next != NULL){
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=temp;
    }
    free(temp);
}

void display(hexString* ptr){
    if (head==NULL){
        printf("There is nothing here");
    }
    else{
        hexString* ptr;
        while(ptr != NULL){
            printf("%s", ptr->data);
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}


char* H2B_MAP(char hex){
    switch(hex){
        case'0':
            return "0000";
        case'1':
            return "0001";
        case '2':
            return "0010";
        case '3':
            return "0011";
        case '4':
            return "0100";
        case '5':
            return "0101";
        case '6':
            return "0110";
        case '7':
            return "0111";
        case '8':
            return "1000";
        case '9':
            return "1001";
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            return "1010";
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            return "1011";
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            return "1100";
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            return "1101";
        case 'E':
        case 'e':
            return "1110";
        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            return "1111";
    }
}

int hexToBinary(char* hex){ //no need for 0x formatting
    hexString x;
    hexString* x_ptr =&x;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(hex); i++){ //internally it is a linked list storing strings so how would you do that, ie convert each number into a different number
        add(H2B_MAP(hex[i]), x_ptr);
    }
    display(x_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `sizeof(hex)` to do in `hexToBinary`? Try adding: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(hex));` and you will be surpriced...

Comment: Thank you so much i will spend the next while learning how to compile using teh command line and learning how to use gdb

Answer (score 1):

You're freeing memory after keeping a reference pointing to the block! Remove the call to `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems/bugs in your code but let's start here:

> I don't really know how to debug using gdb considering it is in assembly

If you want to be a programmer you must learn how to use a debugger. So stop writing code for now. Instead spend your time learning how to use a debugger. There are several debuggers avaible. Text based debuggers like gdb but also gui based debuggers that are quite easy to use once they are setup correctly. Choose one and learn how to use it. For gdb it's not correct that you only have assembly. Most likely you didn't compile your code with `-g`. There are several post on stackoverflow about using gdb (e.g. [Problems with gdb: No debugging symbols found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63647073/4386427)). Just search and read until you master using gdb.

The next step is about **compiler warnings**. Your code have many statements that most compilers will warn about. **Never ignore warnings !!** Fix all warnings before executing the code.

**If you didn't get any warnings**, it's because you are compiling with too few compiler options. If you are using gcc at least do:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic h2b.c -o h2b
```

Even better do:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror h2b.c -o h2b
```

as `-Werror` turns all warnings into errors so that you are forced to fix all warnings.

Compiling your code like that gives me:

```
h2b.c: In function 'display':
h2b.c:40:25: error: unused parameter 'ptr' [-Werror=unused-parameter]
   40 | void display(hexString* ptr){
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
h2b.c: In function 'hexToBinary':
h2b.c:100:19: error: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'long unsigned int' [-Werror=sign-compare]
  100 |     for(int i=0; i<sizeof(hex); i++){ //internally it is a linked list storing strings so how would you do that, ie convert each number into a different number
      |                   ^
h2b.c: In function 'H2B_MAP':
h2b.c:95:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
   95 | }
      | ^
h2b.c: In function 'display':
h2b.c:46:19: error: 'ptr' may be used uninitialized [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   46 |         while(ptr != NULL){
      |                   ^
h2b.c:45:20: note: 'ptr' was declared here
   45 |         hexString* ptr;
      |                    ^~~
In function 'display',
    inlined from 'hexToBinary' at h2b.c:103:5,
    inlined from 'main' at h2b.c:9:9:
h2b.c:46:19: error: 'ptr' may be used uninitialized [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   46 |         while(ptr != NULL){
      |                   ^
h2b.c: In function 'main':
h2b.c:45:20: note: 'ptr' was declared here
   45 |         hexString* ptr;
      |                    ^~~
In function 'display',
    inlined from 'hexToBinary' at h2b.c:103:5:
h2b.c:46:19: error: 'ptr' is used uninitialized [-Werror=uninitialized]
   46 |         while(ptr != NULL){
      |                   ^
h2b.c: In function 'hexToBinary':
h2b.c:45:20: note: 'ptr' was declared here
   45 |         hexString* ptr;
      |                    ^~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Go ahead and fix all these warnings/errors. Then you'll find most of the bugs in your code.

There are some bugs you won't find just by fixing warnings. So here are some extra tips:

`free(temp);` is wrong. Don't free the memory until you are done using it.

`sizeof(hex)` is not doing what you expect. Maybe consider `strlen` instead.

The code

```
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("%s", ptr->data);
    }
```

is an endless loop. `ptr` must be changed inside the `while` to avoid an endless loop.